# Passing a variable to another class

Tags: c#, parameter-passing

I'm working in C# and having trouble passing a variable back to a function thats inside a button click.

So I have a form with a button on it.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int count = 0;
    new EvaluateQuery().RunQuery(_Query,count);
```

I have a count variable initialized to **0**. It passes this value to another function. It serves as the index for an array in my `EvaluateQuery` function.

Basically, the function does some magic and stops. Once the magic is done, I increment my `count` variable. The incremented value should be then passed back to my `EvaluateQuery` function, so if the button is clicked again, it can pass a value of **1** to my function and so on and so on. I'm having trouble passing the incremented value back though.

I am really at a standstill on this. Any help on this topic would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to pass the count by ref. Check this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/14akc2c7.aspx for more details. Why can't you make the function return the count instead?

Comment: on button click alway your count will come to 0 again

Answer (score 3):

If `count` is intended to be modified by `RunQuery` then it needs to be passed by `ref`. Alternatively, that function could return the count, and you could just assign it.

Either way, you have the larger problem of `count` having function scope. This means that the variable is lost when the function exits, and recreated when it is called again (in this case, each time the user clicks the button).

`count` should be in the **class** scope to fix this issue, as its lifetime will be that of the form.